# Помогите составить регулярку PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

> http://torrent2/o-skripte/**3**-post4.html
>   Жирным выделил то, что нужно получить (цифру 3).
>   http://torrent2 - это часть постоянная 
>   `/o-skripte/` -  эта может быть, а может и не быть в урле 
>   `3` - id новости. Его и нужно вытащить 
>   `-post4.html` - часть постоянно будет меняться.

Нужно вытащить именно ID (в нашем случае цифру 3), что находится между

```
http://torrent2/o-skripte/
```

и

```
-post4.html
```

Помогите, уже голову сломал.

Ссылки могут быть и такого вида:

> ```
> http://torrent2/3-post4.html
> http://torrent2/o-skripte/podcateg/3-post4.html
> ```

Id везде стоит цифрой и после него идет тире.

Comment: Вставляю в pregmatch вашу регулярку, но получаю ошибку preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант: `/\d+(?=-\w+.html)/g`

UPD: вот, пример использования в `preg_match`

```
$url = 'http://torrent2/o-skripte/podcateg/3-post4.html';

$extract = array();
preg_match('~\d+(?=-\w+.html)~', $url, $extract);

echo $extract[0];
```

`$extract[0]` - и есть ваше значение (в примере - "3")

Comment: помогите сделать это для php preg_match, вставляю код, но он не работает.

Comment: @LEX дополнил свой ответ примером. Скорее всего вы пытались получить результат выполнения функции ```preg_match```, а она работает слегка иначе. В ней используется ссылка на переменную, которая в последствии будет заполнена массивом совпадений.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
/\d+(?=-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.html)/g
```